# .M3U8 file is not playing in firefox by jwplayer

Tags: firefox, web, jwplayer

Trying to play HLS video (.m3u8) by jwplayer in website. It is playing in Chrome but firefox can't play it. showing message as bellow - 
Erorr Processing: Unable to process segment ..

Comment: Please give us a link to your site.

Comment: Please provide a link.

Comment: The issue has been solved. Problem was with wrong library key of paid version.